# Cancelling a chain of consecutive aynscronous requests

Tags: rxjs

Let's say a user input triggers an http request A, with the result of A, the application must make another request B and show the final result.

If a new user input is received, all http requests should be cancelled.

The example I have is chaining switchMaps. New clicks will abort and restart the first switchMap request. New output from the first switchMap will cancel & restart the 2nd. But, a click will not restart the 2nd switchMap.

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to rethink this. Cancelling requests is the goal, filtering/ignoring results is cheating :).

http://jsbin.com/roranoh/4/edit?js,console

```
function obFc(name) {
  return {
    next: function (x) { console.log(name+ ' - ' + x)  },
    error: function (err) { console.log(name +' error ' + err) },
    complete: function () { console.log(name +' done') },
  }
};

function simulateHttp(val: any, delay:number) {
    return Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(delay);
}

click1$ = Rx.Observable.of('1').delay(1000);
click2$ = Rx.Observable.of('2').delay(4000);

click$ = Rx.Observable.merge( click1$, click2$ );
click$.subscribe( obFc('Click') );

click$
  .switchMap( (val) => {
    console.log('Fetching data A' + val);
    return simulateHttp(val + " A", 2000);
  })
  .do((v)=> console.log('received:' + v))
  .switchMap( val => {
    console.log('Fetching data B')
    return simulateHttp( val + " B", 2000);
  })
  .subscribe( obFc('Finished ') );
```

PS: I have seen some similar questions, although they seem to be very specific, I have tried to be as generic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the second `switchMap` so that it's directly chained to the `simulateHttp` that's within the first `switchMap`:

```js
click$
  .switchMap( (val) => {
    console.log('Fetching data A' + val);
    return simulateHttp(val + " A", 2000)
      .do((v)=> console.log('received:' + v))
      .switchMap(val => {
        console.log('Fetching data B')
        return simulateHttp(val + " B", 2000);
      });
  })
  .subscribe(obFc('Finished'));
```

Then, when another click occurs, the entire chain composed within the outer `switchMap` will be unsubscribed.

Also, the inner `switchMap` will never need to switch - as a HTTP observable will only emit once - so `mergeMap` could be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! For 2 nested levels, I like this, but with 3 or 4 successive requests the nesting gets a little messy.

Comment: If you want to switch on the click, you only need one level of nesting. As mentioned in the answer, the inner `switchMap` is redundant and `mergeMap` could be used instead. Just compose whatever else you want after the `mergeMap`. You shouldn't need to nest again.

Comment: Ah ok yes I see now. Tested and works a charm, thank you very much!